# Why is my Macbook Air6,1 (2013) with Lubuntu 16.04 getting so hot (temperature)?

Tags: lubuntu, macbook, temperature

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook Air6,1 i5 with Boot-ROM-Version MBA61.0099.B20 and SMC-Version 2.12f137.

I used rEFInd for this.

All is working well, but the laptop is getting much warmer than when running OS X 10.9.5 and I cannot find anything on google relating to this problem. I am just using the browser.

[image]

Comment: Can you install psensor and post the temperatures it is reproting?

Comment: I added the outpout.

Comment: Your temps are fine, I don't think you have anything to worry about. You only need to start worrying when your temps get to >85C

Comment: those are temps 5 min after switching it on. it is definitely getting warmer than in OS X.